# Excel count if two columns match and third column meets value

Tags: excel

So here's a generic version of my Excel sheet:

```
A   | B   | C
PM1   PM2   YES
PM2   PM3   NO
PM3   PM4   YES
```

I need to be able to say -IF- `C` is `YES` -AND- the data in column `B` next to the `YES` value also exists *anywhere* in column `A` to -COUNT- the total number of instances in column `B`.

I'm fairly certain `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A2:A20,B6:B20))` gives me a count of identical values between `A` and `B`, but I can't figure out how to make it to be dependent on whether or not `C` on the same line as the `B` has the value of `YES`.  It has to do with an `IF` statement, right?

I could do it in PowerShell in 5 minutes, but my Excel formula skills are lacking, at best.  Please assist.

Comment: @Brian for C1:C20, if the value is `YES` AND the value in column B next to the `YES` value also exists _anywhere_ in column A, then give me the total number of instances where that occurs.  Does that help?

Comment: Total number in what column? I reread your post and it looks like you want the total number from `Column B`.

Comment: Correct.  I want the total number of values in Column `B` only if the value in `C` is `YES` AND the value in `B` also exists _anywhere_ in column `A`.

Comment: See my solution below. I think that is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right path for the SUMPRODUCT:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1:B3,A:A,0))*(C1:C3="YES"))
```

[image]

Comment: I think you nailed it, sir.  Give me a bit to vet it and I'll mark this as correct.  Thanks!

Comment: Addendum:  if I have the same issue, but I want it everywhere `B` doesn't match `A`, how do I reverse that?  Does the `!` flag work somewhere in Excel?  So if `C` is `YES`, I want it to tell me everywhere `B` 's value _doesn't_ also appear in `A`.

Comment: No it does not.  Just change the `ISNUMBER` to `ISERROR`

Comment: Amazing.  Genius.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is what you are looking for?

```
=IF(AND(C2="Yes",COUNTIF($A:$A,B2)>0),COUNTIF($B:$B,B2),0)
```